# Retry sqlalchemy connection on startup when database not ready

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I'm using docker-compose to coordinate a swarm of docker containers -- among them, a database and web server.

When the webserver starts up it expects the database to be available to connect to. But it's not.

Docker documentation offers `wait-for-it` as a workaround -- but I'd rather do as they [ultimately suggest](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/):

> The best solution is to perform this check in your application code, both at startup and whenever a connection is lost for any reason.

I can't, however, find any mention of this in sqlalchemy docs. Should I begin writing my own try/catch for this?